# How to print remote from Linux Server to Windows Printer Server

Tags: windows-server-2012, rhel, ipp-protocol

Now I have the need to print a document from RHEL server to a Windows Printer Server, the protocol to be use is IPP.

The reason why protocol IPP is because on Windows Server 2012, LPD and LPR Services are deprecated, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/jj134163%28v%3dws.11%29

Another good reason to use IPP: https://www.pwg.org/ipp/everywhere.html

My question is, which is the best way on RHEL system to send a document to be printed to Windows Server Printer though IPP protocol?

Comment: Which component is actually creating the document and what is the source format of this document? In case you have a server application that produces e.g. pdf documents a more straightforward solution could be to send the pdf document directly to the windows server print queue (e.g. via the ipptool command). Then you don't have to deal with printer setup and pdl conversion at all.

Comment: Are postscript documents, my idea is that printer setup configuration will do it out of RHEL machine, Windows Server could be possible. My first need is to keep away this RHEL machine from any type of setup/configuration process related about printers. RHEL machine is only a print client and only have to manage the poscript file to be printed and the id of the printer to be send it. 
The idea to use Windows Server as a printer server is a good thing I guess.

Comment: In this case your rhel server could just use the ipptool to send the Postscript-file to your print server. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232082

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to implement printing on linux involves [CUPS](https://www.cups.org/documentation.html). Assuming that Windows Server 2012 implements the (server side) ipp-protocol you should be able to [setup a printer/queue in CUPS](https://linuxaria.com/article/how-to-add-a-printer-in-ubuntu-or-linux-mint-with-cups) that uses the (client side) ipp-protocol.

Eventually you could use [RHELs admin interface](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-printing-ipp-printer) to add an ipp printer.

I don't think there is a specific driver for "Windows Server 2012". You rather should select something like "Generic Postscript (color)" - depending on what [PDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_description_language) your printer or print server supports.

The usual linux print tools/commands/libraries should now work. For internal print job submission (e.g. [`lp` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lp.1.html)) they usually don't use the ipp-protocol but that doesn't matter for you. CUPS will queue the print job and use the configured protocol to forward the print job to the print queue on your Windows Server.