# IPP Printing in C# - Is it possible?

Tags: c#, printing, intel-ipp

We have two offices which are linked by a secured VPN (I'm not IT, so I'll try to explain as best I can).

During a recent audit, it was noted our file transfers of PDF files to the printers in the other office were open to packet sniffing at the switches, which is prior/after connection to the VPN.

To ensure security, a recommendation was to use IPP to submit the files directly to the printer.

I've tried various techniques, but I cannot find a solution to using IPP with C#.

Is this possible or should I look for an alternate solution?

Comment: You could create a printing service and consume it using WCF with a secure (https) endpoint. That way you will have secured it at the App level and, when travelling through the VPN, also at comm. level.

Comment: I wanted to keep this simplified, but more info is needed, I think.
We have several apps running which generate the PDF files. 
Currently, they all reside on the server.

The other office sets up the printers, then drags the files to from the server to the printer using a folder share.

The printers are already set up for IPP transfer.

I just don't see any information of using anything within the .NET framework to send the files directly to the printer via IPP.

Comment: A windows service using a filewatcher?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your print destination supports it you should use IPPS instead of IPP.
I don't understand why you'd have to write C# code to do this, but if that's what you want you might use the external `ipptool` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232082/printing-using-ipp-without-drivers-ipp-client).
Or look at my [very basic implementation](https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-printjob-java) and port it to C#.